# Responsive canvas doesn't scale when getting values from parentElement.clientWidth and parentElement.clientHeight

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, responsive-design

OK I've got this canvas I want to be responsive and scale with it's parent element.

When I use this javascript function to get the values from parentElement both console.log show correct values but the canvas doesn't scale.

```
        this._resizeBoard = () => {    
            var clientWidth = canvasNode0.parentElement.clientWidth;
            var clientHeight = canvasNode0.parentElement.clientHeight;
            var newWidth = String(clientWidth + 'px');
            var newHeight = String(clientHeight + 'px');

            console.log(newWidth, newHeight);

            canvasNode0.style.width = newWidth;
            canvasNode0.style.height = newHeight;

            console.log('canvas: ', canvasNode0.style.width, canvasNode0.style.height);
        }
```

And when I hardcode the values the canvas does scale.

```
        this._resizeBoard = () => {    
            var clientWidth = 50;
            var clientHeight = 50;
            var newWidth = String(clientWidth + 'px');
            var newHeight = String(clientHeight + 'px');

            console.log(newWidth, newHeight);

            canvasNode0.style.width = newWidth;
            canvasNode0.style.height = newHeight;

            console.log('canvas: ', canvasNode0.style.width, canvasNode0.style.height);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your dynamic version, how correct or not are the dims reported by your first console.log()?

Comment: Hmmm... And if I ask for the the dims in the 2nd console.log() I guess you'll say "correct" too? So what when examining the resulting properties with Firebug?

Comment: When i inspect, same values

Comment: So could you edit your question to show the involved HTML part?

Comment: How can you tell that the canvas isn't scaling? Note that canvas elements do not scale like images.